# Bash, How to put output of nc commad to var

Tags: bash

I am trying to put the output of the next command to a variable in a script:

```
pass=x
for pin in {0000..9999};
then
    ans=`echo $pass $pin | nc localhost 30002
    echo $ans
done
```

but the script got stuck after the first try. I know that it should print Wrong or correct as the output of the nc.

Comment: The problem here is in the output of the nc. Both solution down here did work with different output

Comment: Please clarify what is the service behind because otherwise the question will become very unclear

Comment: You are write. But actually I don't really know, because I didn't wrote it. It part of a challenge of Over The Wire. @Ninov for any other service your answers would work. So I think that that it's worth to leave without my last edit. What do you think?

Comment: It's up to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in this way.

```
ans=`echo $pass $pin  $(nc localhost 30002)`
echo $ans
```

Comment: Maybe second line should be `echo $ans`

Comment: Yeah you right about the second line. I missed when I typed it here. But this one didn't work, still stuck. The shell shows empty line after that

Comment: It works in this way. may be `ns` is not returning result. check with this line  ```x=`echo a b $(echo test)` ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change those two lines on this way:

```
ans=$(echo $pass $pin | nc localhost 30002)
echo $ans
```

to assign result of `nc` command to `ans` variable and print this variable